# Could I include more than two environments inside Apigee?

Tags: environment, apigee

I want to include dev, test, preprod, prod and maybe some other environment inside my Apigee organization. I was searching on the Apigee docs and inside environment configuration, and I could not find instructions on how to do that. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a physical standpoint there's no limit on the number of environments you can have in Apigee.  On-premises customers can add their own environments. Apigee Edge (enterprise) customers need to open a request with Apigee Support.  The free Developer product only supports test and prod.

Side note: environments share hardware. So if you have a dev-test and prod environment in the same org and load test your dev-test environment you're on the same hardware (and therefore load testing) your prod environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have as many as you'd like. I know we have at least three different environments in apigee (dev, stage and prod). You can get in touch with Apigee support regarding this.